# get json array from web service url

Tags: android, json, web-services, url, prestashop-1.6

I want to get some json object or son array from my prestashop web service. I can get my json in browser by url with AppKey. but this request not worked in android request.my son object is null because http request can't receive it. **my question is how to get this son by request in android , browsers can get it successfully.**

this is my json response in browser:

```
{"products":[{"id":107},{"id":120},{"id":767},{"id":26},{"id":27}]}
```

but I can't get this json in android, or maybe my request is wrong:

```
public class Asyncs {
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray jsonArrays = new JSONArray();

 public class GetProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {

    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(
            String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://MyApp-Key@elsevan.com/api/products", "GET", params);
        Log.d(" Products: >>>>>>>>>> ", json.toString());
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrays.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonArrays.getJSONObject(i);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return test;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<String> result) {

    }
}
}
```

my log:

```
2540-2553/? E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
09-03 12:43:20.444    2540-2553/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6270288)
09-03 12:43:20.444    2540-2553/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Requests.Asyncs$GetProduct.doInBackground(Asyncs.java:61)
        at Requests.Asyncs$GetProduct.doInBackground(Asyncs.java:31)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Not really an answer or something, but you can maybe try the Retrofit library for get json from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem . it was http client authorize:

```
client.setBasicAuth("MyApp-Key", "");
        client.get("http://elsevan.com/api/products/107", new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                Log.d("android OK", response.toString());
            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never getting a json array, your "json" should be an Array. Ones you get your json response ("products" is the Json Array) you must do something like this:

```
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://MyApp-Key@elsevan.com/api/products", "GET", params);

    JSONArray json_products = json.getJSONArray("products");

    for(int i = 0; i < json_products.length(); i++ {

        JSONObject c = json_products.getJSONObject(i);

        Log.e("Object ID:", c.getString("id");
    }
```

Also, did you check the actual json? Are you getting that exactly response? The null pointer over doInBackground it's because you are calling a jsonArray totally null.

Comment: my problem is getting son by request

Comment: did you try using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ ? it's a really good async with all the GET, POST, PUT, DELETE request in a simple steps.

Comment: I used it , very good. but it runs onFailure methode . because it can't do http request correctly. my request error response is :B@53790420

Comment: loopj response is using bytes... you need to "parse" the response from Bytes to Strings. Like this: String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); and check if API is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://MyApp-Key@elsevan.com/api/products", "GET", params);

JSONArray array = json.get("products"); 

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ {
     JSONObject c = jsonArrays.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Comment: nope! it doesn't work! it requires username again. in browsers, this link requires user pass! My answer worked successfully.